# iOS Dropdown Menu?

Tags: ios, swift

I'm making an app in which I want the user to be able to select the unit of time which they want something to be added for (seconds, minutes, hours). How can I create a dropdown menu that allows the user to select which unit of time they want to use? A good example of what I want to achieve would be in Google's mobile sign up page.

[image]

Comment: Sounds like what you are looking for is the `UIDatePicker`. You can set its `mode` to `Time` to have it present time only.

Comment: A `UIDatePicker` doesn't provide a way to tap on a box which will bring up the options. It also doesn't give me a way to only offer 3 options to the user. Using the `Time` mode will just prompt the user to select a time.

Comment: You can achieve this effect with date picker or picker view using a `UITextField` and setting the `inputView` to the created `UIDatePicker` or `UIPickerView`. You can then make a `UIToolbar` and set it as the `inputAccessoryView` of the `UITextField`. The rest of your implementation would be specific to your case and you would just need to look at the `UIDatePicker` or `UIPickerView` docs